# Can I return Hibernate Entities as return value in JAXWS web service methods?

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, jpa, jax-ws

Can any one say to me that can I return Hibernate Entities as return value in JAXWS web service methods!?

Indeed I have some Entities like these:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
...
    private Childone childoneByChildoneid;    
    @ManyToOne
    public
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name="ChildOneId",referencedColumnName="Id")
    Childone getChildoneByChildoneid() {
        return childoneByChildoneid;
    }    
    public void setChildoneByChildoneid(Childone childoneByChildoneid) {
        this.childoneByChildoneid = childoneByChildoneid;
    }
...
}

@Entity
public class Childone {
...
    private Collection<Parent> parentsById;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "childoneByChildoneid")
    public Collection<Parent> getParentsById() {
        return parentsById;
    }
    public void setParentsById(Collection<Parent> parentsById) {
        this.parentsById = parentsById;
    }
...
}
```

And have a service like this:

```
@Stateless
@WebService()
public class MasterDataService {
    @EJB
    private MasterDataManager manager;
    @WebMethod
    public Parent getParent(int parentId) {
        return manager.getParent(parentId);
    }
}
@Stateless
public class MasterDataManager {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public Parent getParent(int parentId) {
        Parent parent = (Parent) em.createQuery(
            "select p from Parent p where p.id=:parentId")
            .setParameter("parentId", parentId).getSingleResult();
        return parent;
    }
}
```

When I call this web method from client I get LazyInitializationException exception :(

I test Serializable and Cloneable interfaces and override clone method but unfortunately it doesn't work, I use em.detach(parent) in manager but it doesn't work still.

Can any one help me?

tnax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is debatable. Generally, you have two options:

- return the entities, but make sure they are initialized. Either mark the `@*ToMany` with `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` or use `Hibernate.initialize(..)`. The reason for the exception is that by default all collections in entities are not fetched from the database until requested. But when you request them from the jax-ws serializer, the hibernate session is already closed. Technically, you can have some `OpenSessionInViewIntercepetor` but I don't think there's something ready-to-use with JAX-WS, and it might be a problem to write one. If you don't want to transfer these collections, you can annotate them with `@XmlTransient` (or `@JsonIgnore`, depending on the serialization technique). It makes the entity somewhat of a mess, but I still prefer it to code duplication.
- Use DTOs (data transfer objects) - transfer all data from the entity to a new object with a similar structure, that will be exposed by the web service. Again you'd have to make sure you are populating the DTO when the hibernate session is active

I prefer the first option, because it requires less biolerplate code, but I agree one should be very careful with entity state management when using it.

Comment: hello dear Bozho :)

I like you prefer the first option, but there is a big problem. Maybe we have a big object whit many relations that we don't like to return whole of this relations. In other word maybe we will return this big object whit some relations in one scenario and return with another relations in another scenario. Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks for your attention.